# Java / postgresql COPY with JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, jdbc

I have a file which i want to import to the postgres database.
I know i can do it with jdbc and copymanager.

My Question is, how can i do it when i'm using JPA.

```
EntityManager em = JpaUtil.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    System.out.println(file2);
    Query copyQuery = em.createQuery("COPY temp_import FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER E'\t'" +file2);
```

This isn't working.

Thanks for Help.

Answer (score 2):

> I know i can do it with jdbc and copymanager.
>
> My Question is, how can i do it when i'm using JPA.

No, you can't, except by unwrapping the JPA connection to get the underlying JPA provider session, then unwrapping that to get the pooled connection, then unwrapping that to get the underlying SQL connection, then casting that to `PSQLConnection` and getting the `CopyManager` API for it.

JPA doesn't have a bulk-loading API.